# Как работает команда cmp и как ее можно разложить его по шинным циклам?

Tags: ассемблер

Как работает команда cmp [AX], AX и как ее можно разложить его по шинным циклам ?

Comment: wth «шинный цикл»?

Comment: команда обращающаяся к памяти (`[AX]`) может как потребовать работы с шиной, если данных еще нет в кеше, так и не потребовать. По большому счету команда вообще с шиной не работает, она работает с данными в кеше. А заполнением кеша и общением с памятью занимаются структуры подготовки команд к выполнению